# Enum values in Composite Component attribute

Tags: attributes, jsf-2, composite-component

My issue is quite simple : I want to create a composite component with a String attribute, Type.

`<cc:attribute name="type" />`
 This attribute will have 3 acceptable values, [TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3]

Is it possible to say my component will accept only these values ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you cannot put a compile/buildtime restriction on a composite component attribute value in the cc interface. You can however put a runtime restriction by checking the value in the cc implementation.

```html
<ui:param name="type" value="#{cc.attrs.type}" />
<ui:fragment rendered="#{type == 'TYPE1' or type == 'TYPE2' or type == 'TYPE3'}">
    <p>The type is TYPE1, TYPE2 or TYPE3.</p>
    <p>Write your component's body here.</p>
</ui:fragment>
```

That'll be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you, it's not a big problem for me...
But I think it would have been quite clean.
Nevermind !